# Apply Haskell Language Pragma to Block of Code (rather than entire module)

Tags: haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to apply a language pragma to a block of code, rather than the entire file itself?

For example, I enable the `-fwarn-monomorphism-restriction` flag, but I have a couple of files where I'd really like to disable this flag, so I use `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of the file.

However, instead of applying this pragma to the entire module, I'd like to apply it only to the block of code where I don't think this warning is helpful. Only solution I can think of right now is move this block of code to its own file and then import it

Comment: Why not move that block in a separate file?

Comment: Tbh, it's quite silly, it's just a very small function and I was hesitant to create an entire file/module for it. Not a good reason, I know, but it also just spurred my curiosity in general about it, so thought I'd ask to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no way to do this, no.

For this particular pragma, you can disable the monomorphism restriction for a single declaration by giving it a type signature. Although I strongly recommend giving a full signature, there may be some situation where that is undesirable for some reason; in such a case even a signature full of holes is sufficient, e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

x :: _ => _
x = (+)
```

will be inferred to have type `Num a => a -> a -> a` instead of `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.